# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module - jsfiddle

Tags: reactjs, jsfiddle

Im trying to build a JSFIDDLE to debug a REACT/HIGHCHARTS issue but get the following error -

```
 SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Here is my jsfiddle -

https://jsfiddle.net/5fcguapx/

I see the error statement in the CONSOLE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since ECMAScript 2015, [the ECMAScript language is split into two separate sub-languages](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-language-scripts-and-modules): ECMAScript ["Classic" Scripts](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-scripts) and ECMAScript [Modules](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-modules). For historical reasons, these two sub-languages are not compatible with each other, neither is a subset of the other.

Furthermore, there is no way to reliably detect whether an ECMAScript source is a "Classic" Script or Module, since there are sources that are both valid "Classic" Scripts and valid Modules but have different meaning depending on whether they are interpreted as a "Classic" Script or as a Module.

And lastly, there is no in-band way of signaling whether a source is a "Classic" Script or a Module, this Information has to be conveyed out-of-band from outside of the source.

So, your problem is that you *think* that your source is interpreted as a Module, but it is actually interpreted as a "Classic" Script, and `import` statements are not allowed in "Classic" Scripts, only in Modules.

You have to tell your execution environment that this source is a Module. How you do that, depends on your execution environment, e.g. in Node.js, it is conveyed via [the filename (`.js` vs. `.mjs`)](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_enabling), if it is embedded within HTML5, it is conveyed via [the `type` attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#attr-script-type) of [the `script` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-script-element)